# How to increment div id name and localStorage content name using for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, local-storage

I'm trying to run a `for` loop and increment a number of things here but can't get my head around it

jQuery code

```
var counter1 = localStorage.getItem('counter1item');
if (counter1 == null){
    $("#i1").html('Zero');
} else {
    $("#i1").html(counter1);
}
$("#i1").on("click", function(){
    counter1++;
    $("#i1").html(counter1);
    localStorage.setItem('counter1item', $("#i1").html());
});
```

When I'm use `for` loop and try to increment everything then it doesn't work:

```
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    var counter+"i" = localStorage.getItem('counter+"i"+item');
    if (counter+"i" == null){
        $("#i"+i).html('Zero');
    } else {
        $("#i"+i).html(counter+"i");
    }
    $("#i"+i).on("click", function(){
        counter+"i"++;
        $("#i"+i).html(counter1);
        localStorage.setItem('counter+"i"+item', $("#i"+i).html());
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You can't declare variable like `var counter+"i"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of your variable definitions has been already explained.

Another problem - When setting `click` event inside loop, the `counter` and `i` variables are overridden each iteration, so that each button will return variable which was set at the end of the loop.

**F.ex:**

If the loop is: `i=0; i<100; i++` , then at the end of the loop `i` for **each** button will be always equal to `100`. And `counter` will be always equal to the last set `counter` +1, because these variables loses their uniqueness outside the loop.

You have to store the `i` variable somewhere, so that it won't get updated while loop lasts, and is always unique for each button.

I'd store the `i` in a `data-id` attribute of the button and set click event on class selector, outside `for` loop.
Also, since the data is a simple string, you can use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

HTML:

```
<button class="counter" id="i0"></button>
<button class="counter" id="i1"></button>
...
```

Script:

```
// no need for this:
//var i = 0;
for(/* i is defined here: */ var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var c = localStorage.getItem('counter'+ i +'item');
    // add data-id to the element:
    $("#i"+i).text(c == null ? 'Zero' : c).data('id',i);
}
// listen for click event on 'counter' class:
$(document).on("click",".counter", function(){
    // parse number from text of the button:
    var c = $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text())+1 || 1).text();
    // grab the id from data-id attribute:
    localStorage.setItem('counter'+ $(this).data('id') +'item', c);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5tr7y4h/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove all quotes around the use of variables. Putting them in quotes makes them a string, not your variable (multiple instances of this problem)...

Like this:

```
'counter+"i"+item'
```

Literally translates to this string:

```
counteriitem
```

Say `i = 2`, you would write it like so:

```
'counter'+i+'item'
```

to result in this string:

```
counter2item
```

Also, I don't see the variable `counter` defined in the second snippet correctly.